# Exclude specific folder from SP sync

Tags: sharepoint-online

After much online research, I believe the answer will be "no," but I wanted to exhaust all avenues *just in case*. My question is, can you exclude a specific folder within a doc lib from being synced? The use-case is that there is the same folder within several of our sites who's contents are GIGANTIC and maxes out memory once a user syncs locally. I know that, once you sync, you can pick and choose which folders to continue syncing from the systray's "settings," but is there a way to turn it off this giant folder prior to actually syncing to avoid memory issues? Thank you in advance.

-Morghan

Answer (score 0):

For OOTB method, we can only use OneDrive settings->Choose folders to stop sync certain folder in a document library.

As a workaround, you can use some third party tool to selectively sync folders.

Reference: [How to Selectively Sync Folders to OneDrive for Business](https://www.c5insight.com/Resources/Blog/tabid/148/entryid/130/how-to-selectively-sync-folders-to-onedrive-for-business.aspx)